# Convert the relevant part in bib file to bibliography entries

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, automation

I have a latex file with a bibliography. I enter the bibliography items taken from  `Bibliography.bib` file with the command

```
\bibliographystyle{apalike}
\bibliography{Bibliography}
```

Is it possible to extract the bibtex entry command only for the used entries in the document?

As an illustration, assume that I have three entries in `Bibliography.bib` file and I used just the first and third entries in the document.

```
@article{first_article,
  title={Title of the first article},
  author={First, Author},
  journal={First journal},
  volume={15},
  number={1},
  pages={23-27},
  year={2020}
}

@article{second_article,
  title={Title of the second article},
  author={Second, Author},
  journal={Second journal},
  volume={2},
  number={445},
  pages={124-130},
  year={2019}
}

@article{third_article,
  title={Title of the third article},
  author={Third, Author},
  journal={Third journal},
  volume={1},
  number={41},
  pages={114-120},
  year={2018}
}
```

Can I obtain the bibliography commands (for all used entries) like below, automatically?

```
\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\bibitem{first_article} 
First, A. (2020). Title of the first article. \textit{First journal}, 15(1):23-27.
\bibitem{third_article} 
Third, A. (2018). Title of the third article. \textit{Third journal}, 1(451):114-120.
\end{thebibliography}
```

Comment: That's basically what BibTeX does for behind the scenes. After a full compile sequence (LaTeX, BibTeX, LaTeX, LaTeX; to be pedantic already after running LaTeX and BibTeX) you should be able to find an appropriate `thebibliography` environment in the `.bbl` file.

Comment: You are right. But my `.bbl` file contains all the entries in the `Bibliograph.bib`. I would like to get a file that contains only the entries I use in the document.

Comment: If you see all entries from your `.bib` file you probably have a `\nocite{*}` somewhere in your document. If you remove that (and rerun LaTeX, BIbTeX, LaTeX, LaTeX) you should only see those entries that you cited explicitly.

Comment: Thanks. I don't have `\nocite{}` but I think the problem is about `lyx`. Sorry, I should have written that I compiled the document in `lyx` before. I get the output as I want when I compile the file on textstudio directly.